# Does the Apex programming language contain a <Dictionary>String datatype?

Tags: apex

I see plenty of references to String datatypes, but is there a String datatype as well for with key-value pairs in the Apex coding language?

The original C# language has them here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Javascript has them here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196212/how-to-create-dictionary-and-add-key-value-pairs-dynamically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We refer to dictionaries as a `Map`. The general form of this `Map<T, U>`, where `T` is almost any data type (except Void), and `U` is any data type (except Void). Type `T` is the type of of key, and type `U` is the type of the value. So for a key-value pair of String-String, you would say `Map<String, String>`, and for a map of, say, numbers to Strings, you can say `Map<Integer, String>`. You can learn more about Maps in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm).

**Edit:** `Map<T, void>` for any type `T` now throws an Internal Server error, although it's allowed to compile.

Comment: Ah, thanks sfdcfox. That seriously is a big help. Really appreciate it.